# How can an arbitrary json structure be deserialized with reqwest get in Rust?

Tags: json, rust, reqwest

I am totally new to rust and I am trying to find out how to I can doload an deserialize a arbitrary JSON structure from a URL endpoint.

The respective example on the reqwest README goes like this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let resp = reqwest::get("https://httpbin.org/ip")
        .await?
        .json::<HashMap<String, String>>()
        .await?;
        println!("{:#?}", resp);
    Ok(())
}
```

So in case of this example, the target structure – i.e. a HashMap Object with strings as keys and strings as values – is obviously known.

But what if I don't know what is the structure received on the request endpoint looks like?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use [serde_json::Value](https://docs.rs/serde_json/1/serde_json/enum.Value.html).

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let resp = reqwest::get("https://httpbin.org/ip")
        .await?
        .json::<serde_json::Value>()
        .await?;
    println!("{:#?}", resp);
    Ok(())
}
```

You will have to add `serde_json` to your Cargo.toml file.

```
[dependencies]
...
serde_json = "1"
```