# Parse json in rust with reqwest and serde_json

Tags: json, rust, serde, reqwest, serde-json

I am trying to retrieve and parse a JSON file using `reqwest`.

I used this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872942/how-can-an-arbitrary-json-structure-be-deserialized-with-reqwest-get-in-rust) as a starting point but it doesn't work with my API.

The error:

```
Error: reqwest::Error { kind: Decode, source: Error("expected value", line: 1, column: 1) }
```

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
  let resp = reqwest::get("https://tse.ir/json/MarketWatch/data_7.json")
    .await?
    .json::<serde_json::Value>()
    .await?;

  println!("{:#?}", resp);
  Ok(())
}
```

The API works fine with other languages. thank for your help.

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "rust_workspace"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
serde_json = "1.0"
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
reqwest = { version = "0.11", features = ["json", "blocking"] }
tokio = { version = "1", features = ["full"] }
bytes = "1"
```

Comment: This is an error in the JSON itself. Which you haven't provided.

Comment: For example, you could show us what the response looks like as a string, by replacing `.json()` with `.text()` and adding the output to the question.

Answer (score 2):

The error happens usually when the response doesn't contain

```
"content-type":"application/json"
```

Even though the content is a valid json you will get that error.

To solve the issue you need to use

```
let text_response = reqwest.get("...").await?.text().await?;
let resp: serde_json::Value = serde_json::from_str(&text_response)?;
```